# Aligning two combined plots - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment, scatter-plot, imshow

I'm currently working in a plot in which I show to datas combined.
I plot them with the following code:

```
plt.figure()

# Data 1
data = plt.cm.binary(data1)
data[..., 3] = 1.0 * (data1 > 0.0)
fig = plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1, extent=(-4, 4, -4, 4))

# Plotting just the nonzero values of data2
x = numpy.linspace(-4, 4, 11)
y = numpy.linspace(-4, 4, 11)
data2_x = numpy.nonzero(data2)[0]
data2_y = numpy.nonzero(data2)[1]

pts = plt.scatter(x[data2_x], y[data2_y], marker='s', c=data2[data2_x, data2_y])
```

And this gives me this plot:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, my background and foreground squares are not aligned.

Both of then have the same dimension (20 x 20). I would like to have a way, if its possible, to align center with center, or corner with corner, but to have some kind of alignment.

In some grid cells it seems that I have right bottom corner alignment, in others left bottom corner alignment and in others no alignment at all, with degrades the visualization.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You want the `extent` kwarg on `imshow`

Comment: I also do not believe that that code generates that figure.

Comment: First, making your background the same color as your data is an _awful_ idea, I interpenetrated that as a uniform background _in your data_ with all-white grid lines on top.  If what you say is true, that the gray is the axes patch color, then you are using some fancy color map with alpha in it.  Second, by default the extent on `imshow` should be 0-> size of image.  You have imshow data at positions < 0 there for you are doing something you are not showing us to make this figure.

Comment: Yeas, its hard to please others here. Beforetime, I always posted my full code and I just heard people saying "Simplify it...", like they just don't want to read at all. When we try to simplify, people complain too. It's hard.

Comment: You did not simplify your code, you just posted code unrelated to your figure.  If you are going to simplify the code then post an image that is the output of that code.

Comment: or more accurately you did not post the bit of code that is causing you problems (which I assume is some use of `set_xticklabels`).

Comment: No, I didn't use set_xticklabels at all. And I reading my data from a csv. Would you like me to put it here? I believe most of the people would just not look at it. But ok, sorry for any trouble that I may have caused to you.

Comment: Your right I am in a bad mood, sorry for taking it out on you (I spent all afternoon fighting an awful library conflict).  However, my points still stand.  It is best you you write the _minimal_ amount of code needed to demonstrate the problem.  The examples should be runable and actually demonstrate the problem you are having.

Comment: It's ok, @tcaswell, I was not kind with you too. And thank you for the tips, I you follow them. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `tcaswell` says, your problem may be easiest to solve by defining the `extent` keyword for `imshow`.

If you give the `extent keyword`, the outermost pixel edges will be at the extents. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(np.random.random((8, 10)), extent=(2, 6, -1, 1), interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
```

[image]

Now it is easy to calculate the center of each pixel. In X direction:

- interpixel distance is (6-2) / 10 = 0.4 pixels
- center of the leftmost pixel is half a pixel away from the left edge, 2 + .4/2 = 2.2

Similarly, the Y centers are at -.875 + n * 0.25.

So, by tuning the `extent` you can get your pixel centers wherever you want them.

---

An example with 20x20 data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

# create the data to be shown with "scatter"
yvec, xvec = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-4.75, 4.75, 20), np.linspace(-4.75, 4.75, 20))
sc_data = random.random((20,20))

# create the data to be shown with "imshow" (20 pixels)
im_data = random.random((20,20))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(im_data, extent=[-5,5,-5,5], interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.scatter(xvec, yvec, 100*sc_data)
```

[image]

Notice that here the inter-pixel distance is the same for both `scatter` (if you have a look at `xvec`, all pixels are 0.5 units apart) and `imshow` (as the image is stretched from -5 to +5 and has 20 pixels, the pixels are .5 units apart).

Comment: Thank you, @Drv. However, I didn't get how to correlate the imshow with the scatter plot to have both plots centered equally. :S

Answer (score 1):

here is a code where there is no alignment problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

data1 = numpy.random.rand(10, 10)
data2 = numpy.random.rand(10, 10)
data2[data2 < 0.4] = 0.0

plt.figure()

# Plotting data1
fig = plt.imshow(data1, interpolation='nearest', cmap='binary', vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)

# Plotting data2
data2_x = numpy.nonzero(data2)[0]
data2_y = numpy.nonzero(data2)[1]
pts = plt.scatter(data2_x, data2_y, marker='s', c=data2[data2_x, data2_y])

plt.show()
```

which gives a perfectly aligned combined plots:

[image: aligned plots]

Thus the use of additional options in your code might be the reason of the non-alignment of the combined plots.

Comment: Weird and interesting, I will revise my extra options carefully.

Comment: Hi, @Baptiste. I have to apologize with you guys that are trying to help me. I tried to simplify my code and I omitted two important lines. I edited my code now. Now, running your data with my code, I get the behavior that I showed here.

Comment: With a closer look at your plot I remark that the "first" square of the squatter plot is at ``(-4.0, -4.0)`` and the "last" one at ``(4.0, 4.0)``. This is your problem. Change it to ``(-3.9, -3.9)`` and ``(3.9, 3.9)`` to get the same plot as mine (or to ``(-4.0, -4.0)`` and ``(3.8, 3.8)`` for left bottom alignment). To do this change the values in the ``numpy.linspace`` calls.